# Interesting and simple missions for text-based game

Tags: mission-design

Can you give me an idea for a simple and interesting mission for online text-based game that doesn't require much reading? Or maybe link to a website with a list with missions?

I love programming, but I hate when it comes to create things like this, because I am not creative at all.

Thank you.

Comment: If this is your approach, your game will be utterly boring. Hey maybe you'll have a nice engine, but it will suck nonetheless. If you do not feel creative, find someone who *is*.

Comment: @Lo'oris - isn't that what he's trying to do? This is a great step in the direction of getting help with those parts he's not comfortable with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heres another good list:

http://www.io.com/~sjohn/plots.htm

Also I second what the first poster said. If you like problem solving and programming, you ARE creative.

Comment: +1 for the encouragement, everybody is creative as long as he believes he is so.

Comment: I know this is a bit of a necrobump, but the link posted seems to be down. Does anyone have a copy or an updated URL?

Comment: Here's a link to the wayback machine http://web.archive.org/web/20081219050531/http://www.io.com/~sjohn/plots.htm

Answer (score 2):

Might be worth having a read through these [common RPG scenarios](http://www.fanpop.com/external/10070). Hard to say if they'll apply directly to your game without knowing what you're doing but they should be applicable to any genre really without too much imagination.

(And if you love programming you're at least a little bit creative!)

Comment: Thank you very much. And not, I am not creative. I hate literature, writing essays and other stuff where it comes to imagine things. I just love solving problems and programming. :) Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

To get you started without reading too much:

Not so distant future. Person waking up without memories. World is controlled by two huge rivalling corporations. The person (our protagonist) needs to do missions and get too deeply involved with both of the corporations to be able to discover his/her past and why he/she has so many enemies.

Then continue to steal stuff from the matrix, bourne, johnny mnemonic etc and then at least I'll be interested in the story :)

Answer (score 2):

How about exploring a space craft adrift in space?  You could start with 15 rooms or areas to explore and throw in puzzles.  Maybe the onboard computer has gained self awareness and actively tries to trip up the player to protect itself (remember HAL from 2001: A Space Odyssey?)  Throw in some rogue androids, maybe some mercenaries are in the middle of ransacking the craft and the player now has to evade them.  There's a bunch of "surprises" you can throw in to this setting and it can grow if you want to expand it.  The player used a pod to escape from the mercenaries and has now landed on a planet. Now we enter another adventure.  The possibilities are endless!

I'm inspired to create my own adventure game now!  I haven't made one of these since I had my Atari 800 as a boy (I'm 40.)  Anyway, good luck and have fun!